# Web API DelegatingHandler Async HttpContext = null Error

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, httpcontext

I have a very strange error that pops up in my application ONLY when i have a certain DelegatingHandler intercepting calls. The gist of it is that when requests go through my DelegatingHandler, HttpContext.Current is null *for the first request the web server receives* only. So if i'm the first person to hit my API after i deploy code, i get the error. Otherwise, i'm cool.

Here is the overview of how the error occurs:

1. A request goes into the delegating handler
2. The handler goes through its entire `SendAsync` function and ends by calling `return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);`
3. WebAPI dependency resolver (I use simpleinjector) attempts to resolve dependencies for an APIController
4. The dependency resolution fails because `HttpContext.Current` is null (trying to get at `HttpContext.Current.Items` for my `IUnitOfWork`

So it seems like thread affinity/context is being changed only within my handler? I dont understand that. The call stack always shows that the error (HttpContext being null) occurs within that final `await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);`. Strange.

Here is the handler code:

```
public class RecipeIdValidator:DelegatingHandler
{

    private static string[] _Ignore = new string[] {"api/webhook" };
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if(_Ignore.Any(i=>request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf(i)!=-1))
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);


        var recipeId = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().Where(i=>i.Key.Equals("recipeid",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (!recipeId.Any())
            return request.CreateErrorResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,"Missing recipeId/api key. Please add this to your request in the form of the querystring ?recipeId=value.");


        CheckValidity(recipeId);


        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have [`UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` set to `true`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440.aspx)?

Comment: I think that fixed it! Testing more now... but initial tests look promising. Ridiculous. How did I not know about this?

Comment: It's on by default in new projects but not turned on if you upgrade. And it's easy to overlook!